# Best way to include & use php classes in Magento

Tags: php, magento, include

I want to use this [mobile detection php file](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/) on a magento website and I want to know wich is the best way to insert a php file and use it across other subtemplates, since magento structure is still a bit tricky for me.

Basically I have something like this main-template.phtml and header.phtml

**main-template.phtml content is**

```
<?php
    include_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect();
    echo $this->getChildHtml('head');
?>
<?php if ( $detect->isMobile() ) { //condition nr.2 ?>
    <meta name="mobileMain" content="this is for mobile">
<?php } else {?>
    <meta name="NOTmobileMAIN" content="this is not for mobile">
<?php } ?>
```

**header.phtml content is**

```
<?php if ( $detect->isMobile() ) { //condition nr.1 ?>
    <meta name="mobile" content="this is for mobile">
<?php } else {?>
    <meta name="NOTmobile" content="this is not for mobile">
<?php } ?>
```

When I load main-template.phtml in browser the second condition is working, but the first one throws out an error "*Call to a member function isMobile() on a non-object*".

What would be the best way to include Mobile_Detect.php just once in my main-template.phtml and then be able to run that condition in all my subfiles like header.phtml which are gonna be inserted also inside main-template.phtml?

Thank you!

Comment: See my answer below. If you put this in the `lib` folder, Magento will autoload whenever you call `new Mobile_Detect()`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you name the file `Detect.php` and place it in a new folder called `magento/lib/Mobile/`, then you will be able to autoload the class without having to use `require_once` or `include`.

```
path_to_magento
  \-- app
  |     \-- code
  |     \-- design
  |     \-- etc
  \-- lib
  |     \-- Mobile
  |     |     \-- Detect.php    
  |     \-- Varien
  |     \-- Zend
  \-- skin
```

**MyModule's Controller**

```
<?php
    class My_Module_SomeController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
    {
        public function indexAction()
        {
            // Will be automatically loaded from lib/Mobile/Detect.php
            $detect = new Mobile_Detect();

            if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
                // Do something mobile-friendly
            } else {
                // Do something not
            }
        }
    }
```

**index.php - using mobile detection to load a mobile-friendly store view**

```
<?php
    # Lots of stuff above...

    require_once $mageFilename;

    #Varien_Profiler::enable();

    if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
        Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    }

    #ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    umask(0);

    // This will automatically look in lib/Mobile/Detect.php
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect();

    // Now you can change this store view, i.e. change your entire theme
    if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
        // Check if a mobile store exists and prepare to load it
        $code = empty($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? 'mobile' : $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'].'_mobile';
        if ( Mage::app()->getStore($code) ) {
            $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] = 'mobile';
            $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] = 'store';
        }
    }

    /* Store or website code */
    $mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

    /* Run store or run website */
    $mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

    Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Comment: Thank you! I've made like Jim OHalloran said and changed the situation. Using your code fixed the issue.

Comment: *Trump voice* - Thank you Franklin, Very Cool!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you include your PHP class as a Block class ?

Create/rename your PHP classe like : Yourcompany_Yourmodule_Block_Mobiledetection extending Mage_Core_Block_Template and put it in your module's Block directory (I hope you have a module)

Create a dedicated template file in your skin/template module's directory and copy/paste your specific HTML inside

Link your Block Class and your phtml file in your module's layout file.

This is the standard way of building a module in magento.

Comment: I'm not allowed to create/modify any blocks/modules in the current configuration. I'm constrained to use just the php file for this...

Comment: Hu ok.. sorry i'm speechless. Just for cusriosity, why is that? why this constraint ?

Comment: There'a a lot of old code which is not written by me and I think they don't want me to break something since I don't know all of it inside out.

Comment: OKay but you know, magento is modular. If you code the right way (respecting magento MVC layers) and if your module is totally buggy, you can just desactivate it. You should code your module without modify any of the existing (core) files and encapsulate your code in dedicated folders in all layers.. It's the best way to work and should be the only one.. Ask your boss a magento training :)

Comment: my question is not focused on magento. I'm trying to learn how to proper use php classes in situations like the one described above. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: I think what Bixi is trying to say is that the "proper" response in situations like this is to change the situation.  Including classes in templates, breaks down the MVC structure and leads to code which is difficult to comprehend and difficult to maintain in the long term.

Comment: I know Bixi is right! I've followed the advice's in this page and now I'm using the class properly :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the actual class itself:

```
<?php
if ( Mobile_Detect::isMobile() ) { //condition nr.1
    echo '<meta name="mobile" content="this is for mobile">';
} else {
    echo '<meta name="NOTmobile" content="this is not for mobile">';
}?>
```

Comment: Not working. Getting "Strict Notice: Non-static method Mobile_Detect::isMobile() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context"

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is your loading the class in your body not in your header, so your technically attempting to use the class before its even loaded in your header.phtml file.

In short move your include_once into your header

Comment: if I do that then the condition nr.2 fails with the same error message.